# Modify document in opensearch python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, amazon-web-services, opensearch

I have some document stored in aws opensearch and I want to add some new value inside the _source like the creation date of the document based on condition , how to do that in python ?

This is an example of the documents stored

```
{
  "_index": "document",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "8d0114e5a75548d6166d017a7aaed521",
  "_version": 2,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "content": "some text",
    "content_type": "text",
    "name": "file.txt",
    "SUBJECT": "text" }}
```